# Python plotly add_vrect very slow

Tags: python, charts, plotly, finance

I have a financial chart and I'm adding vrect to the background to show LONG (green) and SHORT (red) positions.

This specific chart has 76 trades, hence, 76 vrects.

Here is the code that draws these

```py
def add_trades(fig, trades: DataFrame, results: DataFrame):
    trades = trades.itertuples()
    for trade in trades:
        open_date = trade[1]
        close_date = trade[3]
        color = '#50B99B' if trade.direction == 'long' else '#DC244B'

        if type(close_date) is float:  # if last position is still open
            close_date = results.tail(1).index.item()

        fig.add_vrect(
            x0=open_date, x1=close_date,
            fillcolor=color, opacity=0.3,
            layer="below", line_width=0,
        )
```

For charts with low (1-20) trades, is all good, but this one with 76, this loops takes like 30 seconds. `fig.add_vrect` seems to keep taking longer, the more vrects are added.

This will eventually be used for much higher numbers, and I'm concerned with performance.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

The main goal is to show where the LONG (green) and SHORT (red) positions are over a time period.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post a [mre] including a sample data and performance analysis. In my 9 years old Linux(Intel Pentium G2030), it takes about 5 seconds for 100 ```add_vrect()```.

Comment: That is already valuable input. I did not test a simple scenario and just add vrects to test performance. I'll try to do that, in the meantime I'll close the question and will re-open if I can share a minimal reproducible example. Cheers!

Comment: Have you found a solution? @AlexandreCosta

Comment: Nop. I’ve tried drawing small rectangles and it seems to be faster